# MsSQL / Classic ASP - Select statement from time a to time b

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I have quite a complex query that i need to expand but am not sure how to go about it.

At the moment, im using the following query to output a few values.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), pay.PaidUntil, 10) as LastDay, 
       COUNT(*) As PaymentsDue, 
       SUM(sales.Amount) As TotalDue 
FROM UserPaidUntil pay INNER JOIN Sales sales 
 ON pay.Sales_ID = sales.Sales_ID 
WHERE pay.PaidUntil > getDate() 
 AND pay.PaidUntil < DateAdd(day, 10, getDate()) 
 AND pay.Billing_ID = 2 
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(8), pay.PaidUntil, 10) 
ORDER BY CONVERT(CHAR(8), pay.PaidUntil, 10)
```

At the moment, this script get values between 2 dates, 10 days apart and then groups them by their date.

Now what i need to do is change the sql so that each day is actually from 10:01am on day A through to 10:00am on day B

The UserPaidUntil.PaidUntil is the field that has the dates

Im not sure where to start so i thought i would ask if anyone could help me.

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean `UserPaidUntil.PaidUntil` is in datetime data types?

Comment: @Charlesliam the PaidUntil column is datetime yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a tester for this statement.. It will be something like this :

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateAdd(hour, 10, pay.PaidUntil), 10) as LastDay, 
COUNT(*) As PaymentsDue, 
SUM(sales.Amount) As TotalDue 
FROM UserPaidUntil pay INNER JOIN Sales sales 
ON pay.Sales_ID = sales.Sales_ID 
WHERE DateAdd(hour, 10, pay.PaidUntil) > getDate() 
AND DateAdd(hour, 10, pay.PaidUntil) < DateAdd(day, 10, getDate()) 
AND pay.Billing_ID = 2 
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateAdd(hour, 10, pay.PaidUntil), 10) 
ORDER BY CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateAdd(hour, 10, pay.PaidUntil), 10)
```

Comment: Close, but no cigar. The numbers don't quite match up. I see you have added 10 hours to bring the cycle to 10:00am, but the cycle starts at 10:01am and ends at 10:00am the next day. You will need to add 1 minute to the start.